# Remove class member type part from decltype

Tags: c++11, g++, decltype

I ran into I case I had not seen before, while using `decltype` on a member of a templated class. I wanted to make a nicer `make_unique` so that changing type on the member does not cause fixing the `make_unique` calls. I wanted to avoid this using `decltype(member)::element_type` as the type for `make_unique` but got an error. Here is a simple snippet that shows the error (and I understand why it is shown):

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo()
    {
        // g++ gives:
        //   dependent-name 'decltype (((foo<T>*)this)->foo<T>::p_)::element_type' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
        //   say 'typename decltype (((foo<T>*)this)->foo<T>::p_)::element_type' if a type is meant
        //
        // How can I atleast remove the class name from the type?
        p_ = std::make_unique<decltype(p_)::element_type>();
        // g++ gives:
        //  dependent-name 'decltype (p)::element_type' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
        //  say 'typename decltype (p)::element_type' if a type is meant
        //
        // makes sense since p here is dependent on T
        std::unique_ptr<T> p = std::make_unique<decltype(p)::element_type>();
        // This one is fine, makes sense, since the type is known
        std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = std::make_unique<decltype(p2)::element_type>();
    }
    std::unique_ptr<T> p_;
};

int main()
{
    foo<int> f;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, is there a nice/pretty way to remove the 'is a member of' (`(foo<T>*)this)->foo<T>::p_)`)part from the `decltype` value, so that at least I could use the same fix and simply provide `typename` on the member variable `p_` ? The long fix suggested by `g++` seems kind of ugly.

5 minutes after posting I had an idea that I could do

```
p_ = std::make_unique<decltype(std::remove_reference(*p_)::type)>();
```

but that seems to give a parse error.

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly want: what's wrong with placing `typename` before `decltype(p)`? Or declaring the type before, through a `using`?

Comment: @max66 `typename` is totally fine - I want to get rid of the `(foo<T>*)this)->foo<T>::p_` part.

Comment: @max66 I though I could get around this by `*p_` and `std::remove_reference` but that gives a parse error in coliru:(

Comment: @max66 and thanks for the input that the question is unclear - I added the part of which I want to get rid of in the question.

Comment: But `std::make_unique<typename decltype(p_)::element_type>();` compile also with g++

Comment: @max66 oh ok thanks, I kind of blindly followed the initial warning of the compiler, to use the full syntax:) yep that works, if you post this as an answer I will gladly accept it. Weird that g++ suggests smth much more non-intuitive as a fix:D

Comment: I see... yes: compiler error messages, involving templates, are often crimes against humanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply place a `typename` before `decltype()`.

I mean

```
    p_ = std::make_unique<typename decltype(p_)::element_type>();
```